# Some vertices are still showing in object mode

Tags: vertices

I'm not sure why [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgOO7.png) vertices (color green) still showing even in object mode.

You can download the [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o-wSzvHyevG-9ki3lLoTlXeNOHfau-0Z) if you want.

Comment: Include screenshots into the question body please using [tools of the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) so that after certain time links do not lead to 404 page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have 3 faces, therefore some edges are floating and are visible in Object mode. You need to correct this.

[image]